# get the value of a long - a long and store that value as an int?

Tags: java

I am using `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get multiple values, then I am subtracting one from the other to get the difference between the two values, then using that value in the Robot class's `delay()` method. I need this value as an integer because that is what the delay method will take. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Subtract and cast, and hope it doesn't overflow? Or check for the overflow and handle appropriately to your situation.

Answer (score 7):

If the `long` value fits in an `int`, then you can simply cast the value like this:

```
int someInt = (int) someLong;
```

(or, directly as an argument to amethod: `robot.someMethod((int) someLong);`)

Note that an `int` can store values up to 2147483647 (and 2147483647 ms ≈ 24.9 days).

Answer (score 1):

As other answers and comments have said, a simple typecast works if you don't care about possible overflow.  And you probably don't *need* to care because `2147483647` milliseconds is **a long time** in user interface terms.

But if you do need to worry then this will be a bit more robust:

```
long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
long diff = time2 - time1;
if (diff >= Integer.MIN_VALUE && diff <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    delay((int) diff);
} else {
    throw new SomeException("Delays > 2147483647 milliseconds not supported");
}
```

There is also the (theoretical) problem that at some time in the future, the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 will no longer fit in a 64 bit signed integer.  But that's not going to happen for a few *billion* years - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 0):

AS aioobe said

A simple typecast should work incase you're sure the value actually always fits in an int.

`int delay_amt = (int)delay_amt_long`

if it doesn't then you'll have to do some extra processing such as calling the `delay()` function multiple times say n+1 times

where n=delay_amt_long/max_int_size and m=delay_amt_long%max_int_size

where the (p+1)th iteration has a delay time of m so that:

```
delay_amt_long = n*max_int_size + m
```

Alternatively you could some other method to specifically detect and handle overflow.